# Dynamic number of tables that scroll horizontally (Primefaces/JSF)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a dynamic number of 2-column tables that I would like to have display
with a horizontal scrollbar without wrapping down vertically. I've tried many
combinations of using ui:repeat and c:forEach, but I never seem to be able to
get the horizontal scroll to appear.  I'm not necessarily wedded to Primefaces
(I'm using version 5.0), although I like its feature set.

I'm pretty comfortable coding Java, so I can modify the beans as necessary if a
different model makes sense. The following example is the closest I've come,
but the CSS "float: left" on the p:datatable seems fragile, and the horizontal
scrollbar doesn't appear - the tables wrap around. I also can't figure
out a way to display columnGroup headers with the dynamic number of tables.
Any suggestions?

```
<p:scrollPanel  mode="native" style="height: 200px; width: auto">
  <ui:repeat value="#{tableBean.tables}" var="table">
    <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{table.carsSmall}"
                 style="float: left; padding-right: 10px" >
      <!-- Can't use columnGroup with p:columns...
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
          <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Table X"/>
        </p:columnGroup>
      -->
      <p:columns value="#{table.columns}" var="column"
                 columnIndexVar="colIndex">
        <f:facet name="header">
            #{column.header}
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{car[column.property]}"></h:outputText>
      </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
  </ui:repeat>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

Here are the bean/entity classes ala the Primefaces Tutorial:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "tableBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TableBean implements Serializable {
  private List<TableBean> tables;
  private String name;
  private List<Car> carsSmall;
  private static List<ColumnModel> columns = new ArrayList<>();

  static {
    columns.add(new ColumnModel("MODEL", "model"));
    columns.add(new ColumnModel("YEAR", "year"));
  }

  public List<TableBean> getTables() {
    // Populate 4-8 tables
    int tableCount = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 4);
    if (tables == null) {
      tables = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < tableCount; i++) {
        TableBean t = new TableBean();
        t.name = new String("Table " + (i+1));
        tables.add(t);
      }
    }
    return tables;
  }

  public TableBean() {
    carsSmall = new ArrayList<Car>();
    populateRandomCars(carsSmall, 8);
  }

  private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) {
    int count = (int) (Math.random() * size + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        list.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear()));
    }
  }

  public List<Car> getCarsSmall() {
    return carsSmall;
  }

  private int getRandomYear() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
  }

  private String getRandomModel() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public List<ColumnModel> getColumns() {
    return columns;
  }

  static public class ColumnModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String header;
    private String property;

    public ColumnModel(String header, String property) {
        this.header = header;
        this.property = property;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[header=" + header + ", property=" + property + "]";
    }
  }
}

public class Car implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String model;
  private int year;

  public Car(String model, int year) {
    super();
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
  }

  public String getModel() {
    return model;
  }

  public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  public int getYear() {
    return year;
  }

  public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured something out, although there are probably better solutions.

In order for the `<p:scrollPanel>` to show a horizontal scrollbar, the child
container has to be wider than the viewable scrollPanel area. Although somewhat
obvious, this often won't normally happen since many containers seem to prefer 
to expand vertically rather than horizontally.

So the trick I found was to add an extra `<h:form>` with a width of 2500px, which
forces the horizontal scrollbar. I'd rather have this happen dynamically based
on the number of tables, but this at least meets my requirements.

```
<p:scrollPanel  mode="native" style="height: 250px"> 
  <h:form style='width: 2500px' >
    <ui:repeat value="#{tableBean.tables}" var="table">
      <p:panel style="float: left">
        <f:facet name="header">  
          <h:outputText value="#{table.name}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{table.carsSmall}"
                     style="float: left" >
          <p:columns value="#{table.columns}" var="column"
                     columnIndexVar="colIndex">
            <f:facet name="header">  
              #{column.header}  
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{car[column.property]}"></h:outputText>
          </p:columns>
        </p:dataTable>
      </p:panel>
    </ui:repeat>
  </h:form>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

Please feel free to improve upon this answer.